# Не изменяется атрибут внутри ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in blocks">
            <p class="mt30">
                <img ng-src="{{item.photo}}" alt="{{item.name}}"/>
                {{item.name}}
                {{item.photo}}
            </p>
        </div>
```

Почему-то когда отрабатывает, атрибут src и alt имеют значение `{item.photo}` и `{item.name}`, хотя то, что после изображения выводится корректно, и name, и photo выведены.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас абсолютно рабочий код.
Вы точно не забыли двойные скобки внутри src и alt?

Comment: Нет, скопировал, даже ничего не меняя, в результате выводится:

    <div ng-repeat="item in blocks" class="ng-scope">
    <p class="mt30 ng-binding">
    <img ng-src="{item.photo}" alt="{item.name}" src="{item.photo}">
                        Honeywell
                        /images/cms/data/honeywell.png
                    </p>
    </div>

Такое ощущение, что чем-то экранируется.

Comment: Пробовали Ctrl+F5 для принудительного обновления? У меня бывает такое, что оно закешируется, и пока принудительно не обновишь, показывает непонятно что.

Comment: Всё, нашёл причину: в шаблонизаторе, который выводит исходник страницы, фигурные скобки в аттрибутах имеют своё назначение, одна скобка просто отсекалась. Так что это я затупил. (